# How to change SharePoint Library template?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have a custom template applied to a SharePoint document library.
I would like to use a SharePoint default template and apply to the document library.

I am using SharePoint 2016 on-premise.

Could you please provide me the steps to make the change.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Sign in the top level site as an admin

2.**Site settings** >> (Web Designer Galleries) **Site content types**

[image]

3.On the Site Content Types page, select **Document**

[image]

4.On the Site Content Type page, click on "**Advanced settings**" link

[image]

5.On the Advanced Settings page, select "**Upload a new document template**" option and upload the document template that you wanted.

[image]

6.In this site collection, the new document template will be used as the default template.

========================== **Updated Answer** ==========================

**Please following steps:**

1.Open SharePoint Designer

2.Upload the ​custom template to your Document Library

**Note:**

- The suffix is **.dotx**
- Must located in the **Forms**

[image]

3.Go back Documents library as an admin, click on **Library settings** >> **Advanced settings**

[image]

4.On the Advanced Settings page, scroll to **Document Template** section, and type the url of custom template

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like to change an STP template on an existing document library.

Comment: Hi Sam. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!